# Firebase cloud function returns 403

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having some problem while deploying a firebase cloud function. So far the code is very little to keep it simple, this is the entire `index.js` file:

```
const functions =   require('firebase-functions')
const express =     require('express')
const cors =        require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(cors({origin: true}))

app.get(
  "/test",
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({message: "Hello world!"})
  }
)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

After running `npm run serve` and `npm run deploy` I use postman to test the function.
If I test the function from local it works fine, but if I test the same function deployed I get a 403 forbidden error.

In the documentation ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)) it says:

> Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any
>   Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw
>   HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly make these functions
>   public, or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new
>   functions.

But I'm using firebase tools version:

```
 $ firebase tools --version
8.2.0
```

So I really don't understand whats wrong! How can I fix this?

EDIT: I'm adding the url that I use in Postman:

There's no special settings or anything like that, I just copy the url that `npm run serve` and `npm run deploy` returns as api url, I set as method "GET" and I click send:

[image]
[image]

EDIT 2:
running `npm run logs` show only this:

```
2020-05-02T19:47:51.489Z I :
2020-05-02T19:47:57.764Z I :
2020-05-02T19:47:59.869Z N test:
2020-05-02T19:49:08.122Z N test:
2020-05-02T20:01:51.080Z I :
2020-05-02T20:01:51.493Z I :
2020-05-02T20:01:53.614Z N test:
2020-05-02T20:02:39.239Z N test:
2020-05-02T20:19:54.468Z I :
2020-05-02T20:19:54.922Z I :
2020-05-02T20:20:39.288Z N api:
2020-05-02T20:20:39.314Z N test:
2020-05-02T20:20:42.556Z N test:
2020-05-02T20:21:30.541Z N api:
2020-05-02T20:29:33.576Z I :
2020-05-02T20:29:33.838Z I :
2020-05-02T20:29:35.333Z N api:
2020-05-02T20:30:29.021Z N api:
2020-05-02T20:37:34.864Z I :
2020-05-02T20:37:35.175Z I :
2020-05-02T20:37:36.833Z N api:
2020-05-02T20:38:17.906Z N api:
```

And the logs from the firebase console show this:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"projectOwnerEmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/PROJECT_NAME/locations/us-central1/functions/api"}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly how you're making the request, especially the URL path.

Comment: And what does the functions log in the console say?

Comment: Have you opened the function public by giving Invoker role to `allUsers`? If not, you would have to authenticate your HTTP requests using a service account key file ( and setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var equal to the path of the key file), or by using OAuth. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-http-v1-send-requests)